# separate geographic coordinates in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I don't know if anyone could help me I'm learning python. I wanted to know how to separate oceanic and continental coordinates of a dataframe with python. My dataframe contains latitude and longitude coordinates and I want to separate the points that belong to oceans and those that belong to continents into 2 dataframes. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You should probably include a serialization of your particular dataframe if you want people to help you.

Comment: Look for geopandas and join over continent polygons, excluded point would be oceanic.